# Append next line in file when the current line ends with ^M

Tags: ruby, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a file which is output from a tool (queried from a DB). One of the fields has ^M characters at the end of some of the lines. This causes my output to be corrupted. How do I append the next line to the current line when the current line ends with ^M.

My machine has sed, awk, perl, ruby and python installed and I am using bash.

I tried the following using sed:

```
sed -e :a -e '/^M$/N; s/^M\n//; ta' sourcefile > destfile
```

But that did not work.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Karthick S.

Comment: If you are in doubt about what characters you need to replace or match in GNU sed, observe the ouput of this `sed -n 'l0' file`

Comment: I think I should have mentioned the file format in a better way. Sorry about not doing that earlier:

My file is of the format:
L1F1|L1F2|L1F3|L1F4|L1F5|
L2F1|L2F2|L^M
2^M
F3|L2F4|L2F5|

I need it in the format:
L1F1|L1F2|L1F3|L1F4|L1F5|
L2F1|L2F2|L2F3|L2F4|L2F5|

Hope this helps clear it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ^M character your seeing is probably actually a carriage return. You should match those using \r in regular expressions. The data is probably inserted into the database by a system which uses CRLF as line ending (Windows most likely) instead of just LF (like most *nix systems do). I guess they are followed by a linefeed already, so you probably want to remove them, not replace them with a newline.

You might have the [dos2unix](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/dos2unix) command available on your system which can convert those line endings for you.

You probably want to make sure the line endings are consistent first using dos2unix. After that you can remove the newlines like this: `cat infile | dos2unix | tr -d '\n' > outfile`.
If you want want a space where the linebreaks used to be you can use `cat infile | dos2unix | tr '\n' ' ' > outfile`.

As a side note, using sed to remove newlines is hard because sed edits lines in the file processing one line at a time.

Comment: My problem is not just removing the ^M characters, it is also concerned with appending the next line to the current line.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example which also removes the newlines.

Comment: Though this did not directly answer my question, I tried \r\n instead of ^M\n based on this answer. Before this, I had assumed that ^M and \r were completely interchagably usable. Just learnt otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`^M` means ctrl+M, and it's one character, not two. When you're doing your replacing, did you type it as two characters or one?

One character: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (correct)

Two characters: <kbd>^</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> (incorrect, but probably looks the same)

Comment: I typed it as one character using the Ctrl+v-Ctrl+m method.

Comment: OK, well in that case, the answer from @Cédric is probably more helpful. It was still worth a shot just in case...

Answer (score 0):

i hope I understood your requirement correctly. see the test below:

a file called **test**:

```
abc^M
___2ndline


xyz^M
###2ndline again
```

**note** that, the `^M` I typed in vim with `ctrl-v, ctrl-m`

now see the output with following awk line. I hope that is what you needed:

```
kent$  awk  '/^M/{gsub(/^M/,"");printf $0;next;}1' test
abc___2ndline


xyz###2ndline again
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what caracters were present at the end of each line of my file, I used @potong comments:

```
sed -n 'l0' file
>>> 1st line\r$
>>> last line\r$
```

My file was ending with `\r$` at each lines so I did :

```
sed -i "s/\r//g" file
```

which got rid of the `\r` (or `^M`) by rewriting the file in place. Here is the resulting print of `sed` again:

```
sed -n 'l0' file
>>> 1st line$
>>> last line$
```